# How can i make bluetooth connection in every Activity?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am developing an app which sends data to the android with Bluetooth. I can send data and see from the ardunio side. I can connect the device but when I go to the another activity in the app connection has been lost. How can I keep connection open? In the Second class I can connected the device and send the data, if I have another activity how can i use active Bluetooth connection and send data?

```
private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null && activity != null) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        activity.finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
    // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        // Otherwise, setup the chat session
    } else if (mChatService == null) {
        setupChat();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mChatService != null) {
        mChatService.stop();
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mChatService != null) {
        // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
        if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
            // Start the Bluetooth chat services
            mChatService.start();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_chat, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rad_saat = view.findViewById(R.id.rad_saat);
    rad_Co2 = view.findViewById(R.id.rad_CO2);
    rad_sicaklik = view.findViewById(R.id.rad_sicaklik);
    rad_Manuel = view.findViewById(R.id.rad_manuel);
    opn_spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spn_options);
    radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    spnCrd_Options = view.findViewById(R.id.spnCrd_Options);
    crd_GonderButton = view.findViewById(R.id.crd_GonderButton);
    txt_GonderButton = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_GonderButton);

    rad_saat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkButton();
        }
    });
    rad_Co2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkButton();
        }
    });
    rad_sicaklik.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkButton();
        }
    });
    rad_Manuel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkButton();
        }
    });
    radioGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkButton();
        }
    });
    crd_GonderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)  {
            sendButton();
        }
    });
    txt_GonderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)  {
            sendButton();
        }
    });
}
private void setupChat() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

    // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
    mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(activity, mHandler);

    // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
    mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
}
private void ensureDiscoverable() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
            BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
}
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
    }
}

private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener
        = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
        return true;
    }
};


private void setStatus(int resId) {
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    final ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
    if (null == actionBar) {
        return;
    }
    actionBar.setSubtitle(resId);
}

private void setStatus(CharSequence subTitle) {
    FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
    if (null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    final ActionBar actionBar = activity.getActionBar();
    if (null == actionBar) {
        return;
    }
    actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);
}

private void messageHandler()
{

}
public void checkButton(){
    saatList =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"00:00 - 03:00","03:00 -06:00 ","06:00 - 09:00","09:00 - 12:00","12:00 - 15:00","15:00 - 18:00","18:00 - 21:00","21:00 - 00:00"}));
    manuelList =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"KAPALI","AÇIK"}));
    if(rad_saat.isChecked()){
        atananList = saatList;
        spnCrd_Options.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        opn_spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(rad_Manuel.isChecked()){
        atananList = manuelList;
        spnCrd_Options.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        opn_spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if(rad_Co2.isChecked()){
        opn_spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spnCrd_Options.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    if(rad_sicaklik.isChecked()){
        opn_spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        spnCrd_Options.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, atananList);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    opn_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void sendButton() {
    System.out.println("1. Bluettoth adapter" + mBluetoothAdapter);
    modelClass = new ModelClass();
    modelClass.setmBluetoothAdapter(mBluetoothAdapter);
    modelClass.setmChatService(mChatService);
    modelClass.setmConnectedDeviceName(mConnectedDeviceName);
    modelClass.setmOutStringBuffer(mOutStringBuffer);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SendCordinates.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    
}

/**
 * The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
 */
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        switch (msg.what) {
            case Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                        //textViewReceived.setText("Received:");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                        break;
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
                    case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                        setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE:
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                receiveBuffer += readMessage;
                if(receiveBuffer.contains("\n")) {
                    receiveBuffer = receiveBuffer.substring(0, receiveBuffer.length() - 1);
                    messageHandler();
                    receiveBuffer = "";
                }
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME);
                if (null != activity) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Connected to "
                            + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST:
                if (null != activity) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, msg.getData().getString(Constants.TOAST),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, true);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data, false);
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                setupChat();
            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
                Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
                if (activity != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    activity.finish();
                }
            }
    }
}


private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) {
    // Get the device MAC address
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
        return;
    }
    String address = extras.getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    // Get the BluetoothDevice object
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    // Attempt to connect to the device
    mChatService.connect(device, secure);
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.bluetooth_chat, menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.secure_connect_scan: {
            // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
            Intent serverIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.discoverable: {
            // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
            ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public class BluetoothChatService {
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";
private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
        UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
        UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

// Member fields
private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private final Handler mHandler;
private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;
private int mNewState;


public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mNewState = mState;
    mHandler = handler;
}
private synchronized void updateUserInterfaceTitle() {
    mState = getState();
    Log.d(TAG, "updateUserInterfaceTitle() " + mNewState + " -> " + mState);
    mNewState = mState;

    // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
    mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, mNewState, -1).sendToTarget();
}
public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

public synchronized void start() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
    if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true);
        mSecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(false);
        mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
    }
    // Update UI title
    updateUserInterfaceTitle();
}

public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
    Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
    }
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
    mConnectThread.start();
    // Update UI title
    updateUserInterfaceTitle();
}
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
        device, final String socketType) {
    Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }       
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }
    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mSecureAcceptThread = null;
    }
    if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
    }

    
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    // Update UI title
    updateUserInterfaceTitle();
}


public synchronized void stop() {
    Log.d(TAG, "stop");

    if (mConnectThread != null) {
        mConnectThread.cancel();
        mConnectThread = null;
    }

    if (mConnectedThread != null) {
        mConnectedThread.cancel();
        mConnectedThread = null;
    }

    if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mSecureAcceptThread = null;
    }

    if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
        mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
        mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
    }
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    // Update UI title
    updateUserInterfaceTitle();
}
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}
private void connectionFailed() {
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    mState = STATE_NONE;
    // Update UI title
    updateUserInterfaceTitle();

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    BluetoothChatService.this.start();
}
private void connectionLost() {
    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    mState = STATE_NONE;
    // Update UI title
    updateUserInterfaceTitle();

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    BluetoothChatService.this.start();
}
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
    private String mSocketType;

    public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                        MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                        NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
        mState = STATE_LISTEN;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);
        BluetoothSocket socket;
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                    mSocketType);
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

    }
    public void cancel() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    private String mSocketType;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";
        try {
            if (secure) {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_SECURE);
            } else {
                tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                        MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
        mState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
        setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                        " socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }
        synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        mState = STATE_CONNECTED;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (mState == STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     *
     * @param buffer The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an actual [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#CreatingBoundService) which can be bound from multiple activities.

```
class BluetoothService : Service() {

    private val binder = LocalBinder()

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return binder
    }

    inner class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        fun getService() : BluetoothService {
            return this@BluetoothService
        }
    }
}
```

```
private var bluetoothService : BluetoothService? = null

private val serviceConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceConnected(componentName: ComponentName, service:IBinder) {
        bluetoothService = (service as LocalBinder).getService()
        bluetoothService?.let { bluetooth ->
            // ...
        }
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(componentName: ComponentName) {
        bluetoothService = null
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

   val serviceIntent = Intent(this, BluetootService::class.java)
   bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
}
```

See [BLE case](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/connect-gatt-server) for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to use something like dagger? You can create a repository that you istantiate at the start of application.

Then if you need to use it in activity you can inject it with something like this:

> @Inject lateinit var bluetoothRepository: BluetoothRepository